# Star Wars Spacewalks

Tags: star-wars, space

In Star Wars, it seems that space-faring pilots and passengers never leave their craft (with the memorable exception of of Han Solo, Leia, and Chewbacca on the asteroid with the [Exogorth](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Exogorth), which wasn't truly a "space walk").

Do living creatures ever suit up and step into the void of space in nothing but a life-support suit to do complex repairs, board other ships, or just float around outside?

Comment: I don't have sources at the moment, so I'll leave it as a comment. In canonical novel [*Lords of the Sith*](http://www.amazon.com/Star-Wars-Paul-S-Kemp/dp/0345511441) there is a scene where Vader leaves his own spaceship and literally spacewalks to board another vessel. In legends novel *Darth Bane: Rule of Two*, Bane flies "few hundred miles" (as far as I remember) through space from Dxun to Onderon.

Comment: Astromech droids are generaly used for repairs as shown in episode 1

Comment: @Vahx Yeah, that's why I was wondering if living creatures ever went into space.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

#### TL;DR:  Yes, spacesuits - [also known as environment suits, enviro-suits, pressure suits, vac suits, vacc suits, and EVA suits](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Enviro-suit) - appear in some *Star Wars* media;  they seem to be more common in Legends than Canon.

Some characters' normal gear can serve as a spacesuit for a short time - e.g., Vader's suit in the novel *The Journey to The Force Awakens:  Aftermath*, and (credit to Rogue Jedi for this one) Clone Troopers' armor in *The Clone Wars*.  However, I will focus on purpose-built spacesuits in this answer.

---

### Canon:

#### *Star Wars:  The Clone Wars* - Ashoka in a spacesuit

[image]
[image]

---

#### [*Star Wars: The Clone Wars – "Dooku Captured"*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dooku_Captured) - Obi-Wan in a spacesuit<sup>1</sup>

[image]
[image]

---

#### [*Star Wars:  The Clone Wars - Cargo of Doom*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Cargo_of_Doom) - Anakin in a spacesuit<sup>1</sup>

[image]

---

---

### Legends:

#### Spacewalk sequence in the game [*Star Wars:  Knights of the Old Republic*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic)

[image]
[image]

---

#### Several mentions in the novel [*Star Wars:  Darth Plagueis*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Plagueis_(novel))

> The two Sith were outfitted in environment suits that protected them from scorching heat and noxious atmosphere.

And:

> Unlike Sidious, who was outfitted in a thin enviro-suit, the Sith Lord was wearing only a cloak, narrow trousers, and a skullcap.

And:

> Lieutenant Commander Villian “Vil” Dance came out of a deep sleep at the blaring alarm, sat up, and leapt from his rack to the expanded metal deck of the Ready Room quarters. Save for the helmet, he already wore his space suit, one of the first things an on-call TIE pilot learned to do was sleep in full battle gear. He ran for the door, half a step ahead of the next pilot to awaken. He grabbed his headgear, darted into the hall and turned to the right, then sprinted for the launching bay...
>
> Vil nodded, not bothering to salute, then turned and ran. As he did, he put his helmet on and locked it into place. The hiss of air into his face was metallic and cool as the suit’s system went online. It felt very comforting. The vac suit’s extreme-temp-resistant weave of durasteel and plastoid, along with the polarizing densecris helmet, were the only things that would protect him from hard vacuum. Suit failure could make a strong man lose consciousness in under ten seconds, and die in under a minute. He’d seen it happen.

---

#### [*Star Wars: Knights of the Old Republic 4: Commencement, Part 4*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Knights_of_the_Old_Republic_4:_Commencement,_Part_4) comic - Jarael and Zayne Carrick in space suits

[image]

---

#### [Topps **Star Wars: Galaxy Series Four** trading card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_trading_card#Post-Saga_era) by Chris Trevas - Han in a spacesuit

[image]

---

<sup>1</sup>Thanks to Hypnosifl for these

Comment: If you want a reference a specific episode of *The Clone Wars*, Obi-Wan was seen wearing one in the season 1 episode [Dooku Captured](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Dooku_Captured), there's a screenshot [here](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/File:Kenobi_space_walk.png) and another one showing a front view on [this page](http://www.jeditemplearchives.com/content/modules.php?name=JReviews&file=print&id=57).

Comment: Also, [here](http://img.lum.dolimg.com/v1/images/open-uri20150608-27674-1t8vr85_556dd678.jpeg) is Anakin in an enviro-suit, from [this image gallery](http://www.starwars.com/tv-shows/clone-wars/cargo-of-doom-episode-gallery) of shots from the season 2 episode [Cargo of Doom](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Cargo_of_Doom).

Comment: One other little pedantic thing: the image you have of Padme is not actually a space suit, but rather a biohazard suit that she wore in [Mystery of a Thousand Moons](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mystery_of_a_Thousand_Moons) when she was in a lab where a deadly airborne virus had been released by a mad scientist, [here](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/File:Blue_Shadow_Virus.png) is another shot of her in that suit (click "full resolution" to see it larger).

Comment: @Hypnosifl - Thanks.  Removed.

Comment: Also, those second two shots of Ahsoka seem to be an underwater suit rather than a space suit, from the episode [Water War](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Water_War), someone posted one of the same images with the caption "The Clone Wars Water War" [here](http://chow11.deviantart.com/art/Star-Wars-The-Clone-Wars-Water-War-439495447). The first image of Ahsoka in a space suit probably comes from "Cargo of Doom", there's another image of her in the suit in that ep [here](http://jedibusiness.com/figureDetails.aspx?id=361&img=6).

Comment: @Hypnosifl - Hmm.  I found them in a album called "Women in spacesuits", but I'll assume you're right.

Comment: It should also be noted that the Clone Trooper suits can temporarily function as space suits.

Comment: @RogueJedi - So can Vader's suit (in *Aftermath*, at least), but I didn't think that really counted.

Comment: In the Rebels cartoon (S02E14 IIRC), a whole bunch of people spacewalk too, including standing outside a spaceship with normal clothes and a helmet.

Comment: Oh god those kotor suits... WALK FASTER DAM YOU

Comment: @Hatandboots - SERIOUSLY!!!  They serve no purpose except to annoy you.  you literally put them on, walk through the airlock, practically crawl down a short walkway at a snail's pace, go through another airlock, and take them off.  WHY???

Comment: @WadCheber It would be an interesting way to load up game resources instead of using a loading screen.