# How is the vacuum of Star Wars space different from that of the Milky Way?

Tags: star-wars, physics

Take this scene for example:

Anakin is wearing his regular battle outfit with a breathing helmet (whatever it's called irl) while Ahsoka is wearing a full body jumpsuit plus the breathing helmet.

This led me to question what circumstances are like in space in a galaxy far, far away. I recall common descriptions of clone and stormtrooper armour on the Internet stating how they are designed more for protection against environmental hazards rather than enemy fire, including temporary protection from exposure to space.

I also recall reading about the clone pilot outfit in an official behind-the-scenes book for RotS, for which the helmet is not completely sealed. This has the same general design as future Rebel pilot helmets (see below).

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

In particular, the description of the clone pilot's outfit is that it is designed to improve the pilot's odds of surviving his ship's destruction, then survive exposure to space to allow for later recovery back to capital or other support ships by extraction teams.

My impression of space irl is that it is a zero pressure, absolute zero vacuum environment. To survive space, you need a suit that keeps you pressurised, maintains your temperature, and provides oxygen to breathe. I'm not persuaded that the suits shown in the above references would survive space in our galaxy, especially the open-concept pilot helmet design.

Rebels Season Two, Episode 13 clearly presents the situation. The characters are operating in space or near-space conditions, yet they are able to safely expose parts of their skin (especially Zeb, all he wore is a breathing mask), such as the neck area below the helmets. Ezra could even survive for quite a while without his helmet.

So, what do we know about how Star Wars space is different?

**Edit**: This is not a duplicate. The other question asks why people do not wear environmental suits INSIDE ships. My question is asking about the differences between Star Wars and real world space. Spacesuits are mentioned to elaborate on my question as an example: Characters do not suit up much more than what they regularly wear in-atmosphere when entering space OUTSIDE of ships.

What I want to know is how Star Wars space differs from ours, regardless of how unscientific it is. I'm not really looking for an explanation of WHY Star Wars space has certain characteristics, I just want to know WHAT these characteristics are.

Comment: Space of Star Wars can conduct sound - do you really think there's a sound explanation for this? Take a look here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1825/why-and-how-can-you-hear-explosions-in-space-in-star-wars?rq=1.

Comment: Also this: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/120188/star-wars-spacewalks?rq=1

Comment: _"My impression of space irl is that it is a zero pressure, absolute zero vacuum environment"_ That's not actually true.

Comment: I don’t see any humans exposed to space without helmets in those pictures or video. The end of the video looks like it’s indoors. In the first part of the video, it looked like only droids went without helmets.

Comment: @amaranth There are other videos, but I can't recall if it's possible to embed more than one video per post. In RotS you can see an ARC-170 explode and its pilot flying out of the explosion in one piece - the behind-the-scenes book mentioned how the suit helps to protect a pilot from space, so I assume that scene is an obscure portrayal of this trivia - and we can see the exposed area of the helmet. Search up the Rebels episode I mentioned too - titled "The Call" that is about the Purgill space whales. The characters wore helmets but there's exposed skin when the camera goes close up.

Comment: The edit makes it look less dupey but the examples you've chosen are dreadful. You'd do well to delete everything above "*Rebels Season Two...*"

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: It's close enough. Exposure to a space environment will cause loss of consciousness in seconds, death in minutes.