# Do Twileks and Togrutas have PPE for their lekkus?

Tags: star-wars

I remember Wookieepedia says Twileks' lekkus are sensitive and losing a lekku is debilitating for Twileks. I'm not sure about Togrutas, for that male Togruta on Raada in the Ahsoka novel did have a lekku cut off without a cybernetic replacement but still lived mostly fine. *Star Wars* ships have artificial gravity, but fighter pilots do wear helmets, which means that there's still real risk of head injury. If losing a lekku is debilitating, then it makes sense to have PPE to protect the lekkus. But we see this:

[image: Hera, a Twilek pilot, in an X-wing wearing a helmet which does not cover the lekku]

Here Hera is flying an X-wing, but there's nothing to protect her lekkus, which are at a position easily hit, while other X-wing and imperial pilots with more human-like smooth heads all wear full helmets. So do Twileks and Togrutas have any sort of PPE for their lekkus, and for Togrutas, montrals as well?

I suppose montrals can be even trickier than lekkus since there seems to be considerable variation in size and shape of montrals among Togrutas. I don't recall Ahsoka ever wearing a helmet, except a space suit, nor did Clone Wars era Jedi wear helmets when flying fighter ships,  unlike X-wing pilots; probably that's because the Force is strong with them. But I wonder what sort of helmet would a non-Force sensitive Togruta fighter pilot wear.

Comment: ISTR a Legends source, probably one of the *Wraith Squadron* novels, describing a twi'lek pilot wearing, essentially, stockings on their lekku. (And mentioning that, although very uncomfortable, they *could* be squished up into a standard Stormtrooper helmet.) I don't know if that would be an acceptable source.

Comment: I suspect Hera's helmet is more about having read access to the drop-down blast shield and in-helmet audio feed/mic than immediate cranial injury

Comment: @Valorum It still seems that the helmets of more human-like species are used to protect the wearers from head injury; otherwise they can simply wear headphones and goggles, which are presumably cheaper to make than helmets. Then it's not fair to species with head structures not fitting into human helmets. But I don't know how well Rebels accommodate alien physiology.

Comment: @LambdaMoses - If I'm a Rebel quartermaster, I'm buying a one-size-fits-all helmet to go with my X-Wings. You can cut holes in it if you've got weird stickie outie bits.

Comment: @Valorum That would violate Earth anti-discrimination laws, kind of akin to not having wheelchair ramps and not having Braille, putting valued members in disadvantage because of biology. Anyway, Rebels are not on Earth so Earth laws aren't their business, but this means they're not as much of good guys as we would like. Even Starfleet does better than that.

Comment: The Rebellion is very much a 'make do and mend' kind of organisation, running on a shoestring budget. You want special stuff? Go steal it from the Empire.

Answer (score 5):

For Togruta, it goes yes and no for PPE.

Underwater, we see Ahsoka wearing a simple facemask:

[image: Ahsoka wearing a facemask; her lekku are not protected: she also has two lightsabers drawn and on]

However, there are full environ-suits that encapsulate her entire head:

[image: Ahsoka in a full environ-suit; she has her lightsaber drawn and on, the helmet is fully over the head and transparent]

It mostly depends on the situation.  We haven't seen any Twi'lek's crossing in space to answer this question.  If we take Legends sources like SWtOR, then none of the armor actually go around the Lekku.

Comment: What are the sources for your pictures? They both have highly different graphics qualities and while I know there was more than one show that had Ahsoka in it that second pictures just looks _off_.

Comment: The second one was taken from this answer: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/120188/star-wars-spacewalks and I did a search for "Ahsoka mon calamari" for the face mask.  It's a bit of a challenge to try and take screenshots from a tv show as it tends to get blacked out.  The original source for the EVA suit comes from wookieepedia: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/EVA_suit

Comment: I remember in the Ahsoka novel, Ahsoka was lucky to find a spacesuit helmet that could fit over her growing montrals when spacewalking to Bail Organa's ship. I'm pretty sure the vast majority of spacesuit helmets designed for species without stuff sticking out of their heads won't fit adult Ahsoka and Shaak Ti.